# Is there any way that I can get Google access tokens only using API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, uipath, rpa

I am building an RPA process to integrate with Google AI Document and one of the challenges I've encountered is getting the access token and using it during the API call. Most of the time I'm just using powershell by running **gcloud auth application-default print-access-token** script in order to get the token.

Is there any other way that I can do in order to get that token perhaps by authorizing through an API call or anything?

Comment: Where will your RPA process be running?

Comment: The RPA UiPath process will be run attendedly using local machine

Comment: while using RPA/uipath (I'm not familiar with such tools) are you able to perform calls by using your service account credentials as described on [oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest). Could you provide links and documentation about the tools you are using.

Comment: Hi Betjens, so far I haven't use the oauth2 method yet as I'm not familiar with it. Let me have a look on it. Thanks for the suggestion. Here is the tool I'm using called UiPath, seems like the oath2 option is there [Http Request](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/http-client)

Comment: Yes, It look like you should be able by using the UI. You will have to perform your requests as [Create a JSON Web Token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/images/flows/jwt.png) diagram shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token --log-http` to view the API call that perform the GCLOUD sdk and get inspiration from them.

The content that you will see is sensitive and the logs are deactivated by default. To view them perform a `gcloud config set log_http_redact_token false` to view unredacted logs.

Comment: This seems to solve my issue for google auth login testing via Postman! It returned me a key

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get the key now! Does the assertion values inside the body changes overtime?

Comment: No, it's the values (the refresh token is always the same).